# Is there a XAML style snippet site?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml

Are there any decent resources for XAML style snippets?  I've not seen too much love on some of the other snippet sites for xaml.  Styling might be easier with Blend....but I don't have blend.

Answer (score 1):

For editing aid you can try KAXAML http://www.kaxaml.com/ or XamlPad http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742398.aspx both support snippets. For actual xaml code I'd go to http://gallery.expression.microsoft.com/en-us/

Comment: The latter is more what I was after.

Answer (score 0):

I found this on codeplex
http://hackingsilverlight.codeplex.com

Demo site: http://www.hackingsilverlight.net/HackingSilverlightCodeBrowser.html

The only thing I don't like about it is that the snippets are hardcoded, someone could just build a web service and plug it in as the item source I suppose.

I stumbled on this http://xamlcodesnippets.codeplex.com/ as well but haven't tried it out.